# ActionBar in android above target 11

Tags: android

Can anyone help me how to display action bar with save delete email options.I dont get a clear idea when i searched in google.As I am new to tablet I dont understand how to start it in xml .how to design action bar in xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the answers you need here...
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html